# Java Process cannot delete files in use

Tags: java, cmd, process

My Java application runs on a Windows service wrapper and the wrapper writes logs into a DEBUG file. The application has a service that backup and delete this DEBUG file at the end of the day. The service uses a script batch file to do this process.

My problem is, when the application try run this batch file and delete the DEBUG file following error occurs,

*The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

But if I run the batch file or run the relevant script manually everything works well. Is there a way to solve this problem without stopping the wrapper? (Tried to truncate the file but got the same error)

Script I use : `DEL /A /F /Q "C:\MY_APP\logs\DEBUG.DMP"`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just guessing here but it sounds like you need to close the writer before trying to delete the debug file.
It will be easier to help you if you can provide us with the code that writes to the file as well as the part that tries to delete it.

Comment: @Rex The wrapper writes into the DEBUG file itself, I can give only the name for the debug file.
for the delete I use above script (DEL /A /F /Q "C:\MY_APP\logs\DEBUG.DMP")

Comment: Can't you write into a file whose name depends on the day such as DEBUG20180601.DMP for today? This way the wrapper will release the file of the previous day on day change.

Comment: @StephaneM I'm not sure and I looked into wrapper config but couldn't find a way to that, but I'll try since its easy approach :)

Comment: @StephaneM configured wrapper to create DEBUG files for each day, now problem solved :)